# Search in particular column in table bootstrap-vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to apply a search filter for a particular column. I am using a table component example given in vuejs documentation (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#complete-example).

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far, and explain what's not working.

Comment: I am using this example https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#complete-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the prop `filter-included-fields` to specify an array that contains the field names to only filter on.

If the field you want to filter on is called `name`:

```html
<b-table :filter-included-fields="['name']" ... >
</b-table>
```

See the docs at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#built-in-filtering-options